# jQuery .fadeOut() blocking div under

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was checking this example of slideshow and found a strange behavior.

I am using this code but the image under does not show until the above one is done fading out. Why? I expected the image `#above` to fade out to the image `#under`.

(Note that `#above` has `z-index:10;`)

```
<div id="current_image">
    <img width="370" id="above" src="...
    <img width="370" id="under" src="...
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".small_image").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        var image = $(this).prop("rel");
        var above = $('#above');
        var under = $('#under');
        under.prop('src', image);
        above.fadeOut(1000, function () {
            above.prop('src', under.prop('src')).css('display', 'block');
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cVNTG/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the 2 images in the `#current_image` div are not on top of one another, but the one image is vertically above the other image (the images are not stacked).

http://jsfiddle.net/cVNTG/2/

So, you just need to alter some CSS:

```
#current_image {
    width:370px;
    height:245px;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#current_image img {
    min-height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Now your images are absolutely aligned, and they're on top of one another. So as one fades out, the other one is showing behind it. If you had inspected the HTML/CSS with something like Firebug, you would have seen this.

I would consider rewriting the JavaScript portion of this. You don't really need to change `src` and all that. Just assign your `#above` and `#below` id's as needed, and then make sure `#above` has a higher z-index (or really, you probably only need to add/remove the `#above` id).